# Php DOMDocument ::load() works locally but not on the phpfog cloud

Tags: php

I've written a small php script which uses the DOMDocument object to read xml from an external domain. The script works perfectly when hosted locally but doesn't work when hosted on the phpfog cloud.

```
$mlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($url);
```

I've checked the url which is produced prior to the load call and it's fine. As far as I'm aware the method shouldn't be affected by where it is called from (local machine or external).

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible the PHPFog cloud has disabled the DOM extension (either explicitly with `--disable-dom` or implicitly because they passed `--disable-libxml`). If neither of these things are true, can the PHPFog machine access `$url`? You might try `file($url)` if the fopen wrappers are enabled, to see if the machine can access the URL (or try opening a socket to port 80 after resolving the domain).

Comment: I've checked phpinfo() and DOM/XML is enabled. The DOM::load() call doesn't cause an error either but the XML tree is mapped to the object. The script fails whilst attempting to access tree elements (since they aren't there). calling fopen($url) or file($url) returns false as well, does that mean that the cloud doesn't allow connections to remote hosts?

Comment: Try opening another URL (i.e. http://www.google.com). Reading the PHPFog documentation, they mention accessing other services is possible. It may be that they just can't find that URL?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because PHPFog has disabled url wrappers in PHP

```
https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```